# Asp.Net popup error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, popup

Is there a way I can display an error message in a popup box? I'm using Asp.Net (C#), and on our webpage, if an order goes throug incorrectly we display an error message. Now, we would like to be able to do so using some sort of pop-up method (maybe Ajax?) - it should be able to take a string value to display the error message.

Comment: What do you display to the user if the order goes through correctly?

Comment: They are directed to a new page that says "Thank you for ordering...." etc.

Comment: And if the order fails, are you going to keep them at the order page, or direct them to a new page?

Comment: Keep them at the same page, the order page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a simple approach, you can have a script block that contains `alert("your error message")`. If you want the popup to be styled as the rest of your website then you could render your error message into a `div` element and use a [jQuery dialog](http://jqueryui.it/demos/dialog) to display it as a modal dialog within your page.

Comment: Can I display that using C# conditionally? If X then "display alert"?

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit you can do this from code-behind: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"myalert","alert('There was a problem processing your order');",true);`

Answer (score 3):

I have used Ajax to accomplish this myself.

Using the ModalPopupExtender and setting  the PopupControlID to an Asp Panel, I usually put this into a User Control so it can be easily used through a website.

However below is a snippet of the asp.net code

```
<div class="modalPopupAlign">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkConfirm" Style="display: none;" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" PostBackUrl="#">Confirm</asp:LinkButton>
    <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="lnkConfirm_ModalPopupExtender"  runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkConfirm" PopupControlID="pnlConfirmation" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="true" RepositionMode="None">
    </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
    <div id="pnlConfirmation" class="modalPopup" style="display: none;">
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div class="modalPopupContainerAlign">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgIcon" CssClass="modalPopupImage" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" CssClass="modalPopupMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <div class="modalPopupTextbox"><asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" Width="200px" MaxLength="100" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>

                        <asp:Button ID="btnAction" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="defaultButton" Text="OK"  />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does take some time to get it working properly as I have had a few errors with the script manager, which I currently have setup in a master page.

Just might give you a direction to head for, and the CSS can help shape and colour the message box.

Although this is a complex way in some respect but has many uses.

Comment: +1 for the ModalPopupExtender. I used that with great success before moving to MVC and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple javascript like this...

```
alert("my error message");
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx) is more info on using javascript